# With Valid Visa are ther any limits to quantity of trips to the USA

Tags: visas

I have a Friend in Mexico that has a Visa that is good until January on 2023. She is wondering how many trips a year she can take to the United States?Is there a limit to quantity of trips? She travels to the USA about 6 times a year.

Comment: Some people who live near the border come every weekend, or even every day!

Comment: Does she want to make 6 trips of 50 days each, or 6 trips of a week each?  It makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

David Richerby is right: if she has a multiple entry visa, it is valid for an unlimited number of trips.

However, a visa does not guarantee admission to the United States. That decision is made by the immigration officers at the border. If they have reason to believe that she is not using the visa in a way that is consistent with its purpose, they may ask further questions and/or decide to refuse her admission.

If she has a B-1/B-2 visa, it is valid for [various purposes](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html) ranging from tourism to visiting friends and relatives to attending business meetings. It is not valid for work, studying, or living in the United States. Frequent and/or lengthy visits give rise to the suspicion that she may be living or working illegally and will lead to more questions.

Numerous Mexicans with visas come to the US regularly (some, especially with student or employment visas, commute daily) to shop, see friends and relatives, conduct business, and visit. Six times a year is unlikely to be unreasonable unless those visits are all for lengthy stays.

Answer (score 1):

The visa sticker in your friend's passport should have a part that says "Entries" followed by either a number or the letter "M". "M" means "multiple" which I think means that she can, in principle, enter the US as many times as she wants; a number means she can enter up to that many times in total.